# What happens if you’re in the middle of a process when AWSAssumeRole times out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, assume-role

I’m currently working with a role that I need to assume to access certain buckets on S3.

I was wondering, if the duration given to an STSAssumeRoleSessiomCredentialsProvider is 1 hour and you’re doing something like downloading a file that takes 1.5 hours, does it finish the process or does it stop in the middle because the duration ended?

Answer (score 0):

The validity of the credentials is verified when the request is initiated. Once initiated successfully, the response will be sent completely. In your download example case, if the credentials were valid when the download request was initiated, that is sufficient for the file to be downloaded completely.

The STS credentials expiry is a problem where repeated connections are made to AWS as part of a long running program and the program reads the credentials at the beginning and stores them. It is generally a good practice to decouple the sts-credential-acquisition process from the users of those credentials and the users should ensure the credentials are always read when the underlying source of credentials (typically a file) is modified.

These aspects are handled by AWS Java SDK's `ProfileCredentialsProvider` class automatically. Not sure if a similar module exists in other language bindings too.

Answer (score 0):

Credentials are validated when presented on an API call. If you make your API call(s) *before* the credentials expire then you are fine.

If, however, you need to make multiple API calls, and one of them exceeds the expiration time, then that call will fail.

This is particularly relevant to S3 multi-part uploads, each part of which is a distinct API call, and which presents credentials each time. The solution to this generally is one of:

1. get credentials that are valid for long enough to complete the
   operation
2. refresh credentials when you are close to expiration and
   use the new credentials for subsequent part uploads